# when Pressed Back Button on RecyclerView it takes to the Home Screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, layout, android-recyclerview

I have created a Horizontal `RecyclerView`, It has `onClickListener`, When User Clicks on it, It opens `Video Player`. The Problems arises when user clicks on Back Button.

When user clicks on Back Button it takes user to the `MainActivity` and not to the original activity from where user actually launches the Video.

This is what i have done. Kindly guide me how to keep the History of previous activity when opening another activity from `recyclerView onClickListener`

**ListActivity**

```
 VideosRecyclerView recyclerAdapter = new VideosRecyclerView(this, videosList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        lvRecyclerVideosList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        lvRecyclerVideosList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        lvRecyclerVideosList.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
public class VideosRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosRecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public VideosRecyclerView(Context context, ArrayList<VideosService> dataList){
        this.context= context;
        this.dataList= dataList;
    }

 @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_video_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v, context, dataList);
    }


 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        VideosService item = dataList.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText(item.getTitle());
        videoURL= item.getVideoURL();

    }


 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public ImageView imageView;
        Context context;

     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position= getAdapterPosition();
            VideosService videosService= this.dataList.get(position);
            Intent i= new Intent(context, VideoActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("videoURL", videosService.getVideoURL());
            context.startActivity(i);

        }
```

**Manifest**

```
   <activity
        android:name=".gdvl.VideoLists
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".VideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_video"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

**Edit**

This is how i start VideoList

```
                Intent i = new Intent(gdData.this, videoLists.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
```

I removed the History of the activity that starts `videoLists`, but i never removed History of `VideoLists`. This is how is start VideoPlayer

```
 Intent i= new Intent(context, VideoActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("videoURL", videosService.getVideoURL());
            context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It seems that your ListActivity that launched the video player is not in the backstack. Does this activity have noHistory=true in its attributes ?

Comment: No, i have not set any of this attribute. I have launched the same video activity from others activities, it works fine, It creates problem only when launching it from RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);` from while launching video list activity.

It will erase your history.